# multiple equations on same row in array

Tags: align, amsmath, eqnarray

I would like to have a system of equation, say 2x2, and have each one labeled and numbered independently.
Please check the example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align} %---> This works fine
  a + b &=c \label{eq:1}\\
  d - e &=f \label{eq:2}
\end{align} 

\begin{align} %---> How can I put numbers and labels here?
  a + b + c &=d \label{eq:11} & d + e &=f     \label{eq:12} \\
  g + h &=i     \label{eq:21} & j + k -l &=m  \label{eq:22} 
\end{align} 


\end{document}
```

[image: This is how I wish to have the output]

Thank you.

Marco

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align} %---> This works fine
  a + b &=c \label{eq:1}\\
  d - e &=f \label{eq:2}
\end{align}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{align}
  a + b + c &=d \\
  g + h &=i
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{align}
  d + e &=f\\
  g + h &=i
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image]